# Flutter: How to resize a PageView height to take the tallest child height

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `PageView` and I want it to resize the height of the `PageView` to the tallest child it has. The child can have images and texts.

I've seen people using `ExpandablePageView`. But that resizes the PageView each time the user slides the card. I want all the child cards to take the size of the tallest card.

I've tried `LayoutBuilder`, `IntrisicHeight` and few other hacks. Nothing seems to be working.

Any idea will be appreciated.